# Second monitor with an Intel iMac?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mac, dvi, displayport

Is anyone able to attach a second monitor to their Intel iMac?

Trying to connect a Dell 1909W monitor - the connection is DVI cable plugging into an Apple DVI-to-Displayport adapter which is connected into the iMac.

This has been an issue under both Leopard and Snow Leopard, and from what I can tell I'm not alone:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10309922

http://macosx.com/forums/hardware-peripherals/290248-imac-external-monitor.html

It shouldn't be this hard.....right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally called Apple Tech. Support today and spoke with a tech. on this issue. It is a known issue that is scheduled to be addressed by Apple in a future update. He said there is no workaround currently other than to erase and install back to 10.5.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that's what I was told.