# Can't get display on second monitor with desktop

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to use an ASUS V247H as a second monitor.  I've plugged it into my desktop (OS 10.8.4, iMac) with a DVI cable and adapter, and it's definitely being recognized but I can't get a display on the screen.  When I plug it into my laptop (also 10.8.4) it works fine.  Tried every combination of resolution/refresh rate available.  Any thoughts?

EDIT:  Also tried an HDMI cable, again, works with MacBook Pro5,5, not with my iMac9,1

Here's photos of the cables and ports and whatnot, in case I'm wrong in what I think I have.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmtYI.jpg

Comment: For what it's worth, it randomly started working months later.  Worked perfectly for many months, then one day gave out as suddenly as it had appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to an external display on a Mac, turn on the projector or external display, and plug the cable into the correct port on your Mac1. Your Mac will automatically connect to the display and choose an appropriate resolution. These part you have already tried. Now

### Changing your Display Settings

1. Click the Apple menu, and select *`System Preferences`*. The System
   Preferences box appears.
2. Choose Displays.  A window will appear on each monitor allowing you
   to choose the resolution for each.
3. On your primary display, you will have options for arranging the
   displays. To change the primary display, click *`Arrangement`* and drag
   the menu bar from one display to the other. Your menu bar and Dock will move to the other display.
4. If you want
   the same thing on both displays, select *`Mirror Displays`* Close the
   window to save your changes.

Also, check a [similar post.](https://superuser.com/questions/49559/second-monitor-with-an-intel-imac?rq=1)

Hope this Helps..:)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do it normally.  Something is definitely wrong with my system, as the monitor is being recognized but is not displaying anything (whether mirrored or not).  Works fine on my laptop, just not my desktop.

Comment: Did you see the link.. I think it would be better to call the support guys at Apple..